# blindly rename files - linux

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have quite a large number of files that has long filenames, symbols, spaces etc. I want to randomly and blindly to rename all of them all at once while giving them a random filename from `1-9a-Z`. I do not want to manipulate each file name as sometime it throw out errors due to the symbols, spaces, length, etc.

Any kind of help is great appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the inodenumber as a file name. Guaranteed to be unique within a filesystem.

```
#!/bin/sh
                                        # inodenumber+name
find . -name \*tmp -type f -ls | awk '{print $1," ",$11}' | (
        while read i p; do
        # UPDATE: extract the basename and suffix
        b=`basename $p`
        s="${b##*\.}"
        echo "b=$b"
        echo "s=$s"

        # remove the echo after testing ...
        echo mv -i $p $i.$s
        done
        )
#eof
```

Note: this won't work if there are spaces or tabs in the filename.

Comment: Yes, this finally works for me, however, how can I achieve this by renaming everything and still keeping the file extensions?

Comment: `suffix="${p##*\.}"` would do the trick. Probably you should first get the basename from p.

Comment: @thevoipman - What exactly qualifies as an "extension"?  If I've got `backupfile.20120720.tar.gz`, do you split at the first dot, or the last?  No "generic" solution will work in all cases.  Each solution is purpose-built.

Comment: @ghoti that's true. in my case, I would like to take the very last dot for now.

Comment: @wildplasser thanks for your tip, can you please tell me how/where i should put that line?

Comment: @wildplasser how can I make your scrip keep the file extension or the last dot and also make this work for file names that has spaces, tabs, weird characters etc?

Comment: 1) I already edited that into the answer. The `##` version should catch the biggest match (last dot), a single `#` version should split at the first dot. WRT whitespace: that is hard; you'd have to choose another delimiter for the `awk` part, and have the `read` part also expect that delimiter. Maybe a separate `stat` step to fetch the inode numbers could help.

Comment: @wildplasser Thank you for your help thus far. I have attempted your latest script while implementing a $1 to the directory for it to search and it's throwing back some basename issue. Here is the error:


sh re2.sh mp3
b=Untitled-10.jpg
s=jpg
mv -i mp3/Untitled-10.jpg 116457475.jpg
basename: extra operand `mp3/Kh?nh231243853'
Try `basename --help' for more information.

Comment: Probably an embedded space. You could try b=`basename "$p"`. Otherwise choose another delimiter for awk and read. (comma, colon, @sign ...)

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks again for this. I am not experienced enough as I have a learning curve. I will just create multiple files with this script in it for the directories I want to run it in since it's working like a charm! Thanks everyone for giving me the time of the day!

Comment: @wildplasser Is there anyway we make this renaming work for the sub directories as well?

Comment: You'll need to choose first where you want the files (from the subdirs) to be moved to. In the current form, all files will be moved into the same target dir. (please note that "find" searches subdirs, too) This will be Ok if all the directories belong to the same mounted filesystem. (Inode numbers are unique within a FS). Otherwise you'll have to invent something new ...

Comment: @wildplasser I have sub folders that has weird characters such as "?, ', *, etc" I sometime get errors when going into it via this script.

Comment: @wildplasser seems like it works ok for file names and folders that does not have spaces in them. how do we utilize this with file names that has spaces in them?

Comment: @wildplasser I got another error with weird characters in the file names - this is the purpose of why I labeled this questions to rename "blindly" without dealing with what the old directory/folder is:


mv -i ./mp3upload/20120723bTxhJiiLI3rJ7k9.mp3 184745993.mp3
--More--basename: extra operand `./vntv/[DAN]_Vietsub_Wish50004022'
Try `basename --help' for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a simple bash script, like Oli suggested:

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
for i in *; do
   mv "$i" "$counter";
   ((counter++))
done
```

HTH

Comment: let bash do the math: `((counter++))`

Comment: but the trick is to do it *randomly* as he asked. I used the suggested awk script when this come up in constructing a homework problem that involved classifying some files. Renaming had to be random, otherwise you could infer the class from the order in the list of names.

Comment: @peterkarasev: Please see the OP's comment under Oli's answer below. The word _random_ can be taken a few different ways with varying levels of complexity. However, if you did want to create a 'random' string, use `/dev/urandom`. Perhaps something like: `< /dev/urandom tr -dc '[0-9A-Za-z]' | head -c 8; echo`. HTH

Comment: sweet! way better than trying to use date +%N

Answer (score 2):

Oneliner with temporary file names (change directory of your own):

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" `mktemp -p /home/user/temp`; done
```

Comment: +1. You might want to generate the new filename first and see if it already exists `while true; do new=$(mktemp); [[ -e "$new" ]] || break; done; mv "$f" "$new"`

Comment: Hello, I have tried your suggestions and it's giving me errors:

Usage: mktemp [-V] | [-dqtu] [-p prefix] [template]
mv: missing destination file operand after `201207217MsrpnCsa9n6Vht.mp3'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
mktemp: invalid option -- -

Comment: OK, I've changed --tmpdir option to -p. Try now and give me feedabck.

Comment: @glennjackman AFAIK, mktemp is safe regarding non-existent file name.

Comment: @igustin I've tested but now it it's prompting to do an overwrite when i haven't even ran this command yet suggested - also, how do we keep the file extensions intact?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a temporary directory
2. For each file, `mv filename tmp/$i`, where `$i` is an incrementing number.
3. `mv tmp/* .`.

Comment: hello, how do I make $i as an incrementing number?